# Query for events with a date and time greater than now

Tags: php, mysql

all - fairly simple query question that's been hounding me: How do I query for entries with a date and time only greater than now, or when the query is run (page requested)?

I've seen some examples but they aren't good enough for me to modify. Here's my code:

```
$todaysDate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
$params = array('select'=>'*', 'limit'=>3, 'orderby'=>'t.event_StartDate ASC', 't.event_StartDate < "$todaysDate"' );
```

An example of the variable "t.event_StartDate" outputs "2010-12-10 22:18:42" so I assume that may be how it's saved in the database.

I suspect I'm not building the date correctly or I need to be using a time function I'm not familiar with in MySQL. Help? This is for outputting a series of events with date and time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you reverse the use `<`, it should be `>`

try

```
SELECT ... WHERE t.event_StartDate>NOW();
/* you don't even need to set $todaysDate */
```

Comment: Right, I think that's it. I also tried CURRENT_DATE(). They both work but not down to the minute. Is there a way to test to see if the time coming out of the DB is correct for my timezone? So that if I want the event to "disappear" at 7:30 PM EST, it will request that from the DB and not return it?

Comment: `show variables like '%time_zone';` this will return what is your database timezone setting.

Answer (score 0):

t.event_StartDate > NOW() don't will returns nothing? a date higher of now lol. I'm confused.